# Using javascript so that the numerics are right aligned and others are left aligned

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used this javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function() {
       if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
            $(this).css("text-align", "right");
        }
    });
});
```

By this all the numbers are right aligned. But I want that the string entered should be left aligned. I think that by using NaN it is possible but I don't know how to use it. Can some one tell me the way to use NaN or some other function?

Comment: So 0 and negative numbers should be left aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use the `typeof` operator to determine between number and string.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "td" ).each( function() {
       var textVal = $( this ).text();
       var type = !isNaN(parseFloat(textVal)) && isFinite(textVal);

       if ( !type ) {
            $( this ).css( "text-align", "left" );
       } else if ( type ) {
            $( this ).css( "text-align", "right" );
       }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @SnehaKachroo - Oops! modified it now to detect numeric values. Give it a try now.

Comment: Now the numeric values are right aligned but others are also getting right aligned.

Comment: Can some one give some other alternative??

Comment: @SnehaKachroo - I see it working. Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/xerT4/. What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Issue is that even if I give some string type value that is also getting right aligned.

Comment: The example fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/xerT4/) i gave here works properly. Can you post your code in a fiddle somewhere so that we can take a look. Right now, we are shooting in the dark. Please post the code that you have tried with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function() {
       var item = $(this);
       if (item.text().match(/^-?\d+$/)) {
            item.css("text-align", "right");
        } else {
            item.css("text-align", "left");
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MyqrG/

Comment: It is not working, now all the numeric values are also aligned to left.Can you suggest me some other thing?

Comment: @SnehaKachroo - See my working example I've added to the answer.  It works there so there must be something else you're doing in your actual implementation that changes the result.

Comment: seems to be working .. see this.. the td width was not enough to show it properly.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/MyqrG/9/

Comment: You may need an "isNumber" test (function?) to allow for negative numbers and decimals as well as integers.

Comment: @Rob - the OP was using `parseInt()` before so decimals seem out.  A leading and optional `-` can be added to the regex if negatives are allowed.